# What is the visualization parameter of Water Occurance Layer transiting from 1% opacity red to 100% opacity blue?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to display my water occurance layer whose value ranges from 0% to 100% as the [sample](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GSW1_1_GlobalSurfaceWater) in GEE, but I did not find the corresponding visualization parameters in its Data User Guide.

[image: sample]

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script which produces this image can be found in the Code Editor's Scripts tab under **[Examples/Datasets/JRC_GSW1_0_GlobalSurfaceWater](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ADatasets%2FJRC_GSW1_0_GlobalSurfaceWater)**, and its text is:

```
var dataset = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater');
var occurrence = dataset.select('occurrence');
var occurrenceVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'ffbbbb', '0000ff'],
};
Map.setCenter(59.414, 45.182, 6);
Map.addLayer(occurrence, occurrenceVis, 'Occurrence');
```

The appearance is not partially transparent red, but a palette containing reddish white (`ffbbbb`) and white.

Comment: Is it possible to set opacity attribute for each color in palette respectively, that is, the reddish white is 1% opacity while the white and red is completely opaque?   Anyway, your answer is acceptable, since the layer style you provide looks like what I want. Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: @NickCarraway Opacity is determined not by the palette but by the mask of the image. The tidiest way I can think of to do that in the same format is to use `Image.visualize()` to apply a palette to the image and then use one band (red, green, or blue) of the produced visualization-image as a new mask for the actually displayed image.

Comment: @NickCarraway regarding variation in opacity, you might find some helpful code in the [ImageCollection visualization guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_visualization#overlays) as well.